# ReactJS - make text input that contains tags and free text as template

Tags: reactjs, variables, input, text, tags

I'm researching an easy way to make a free text input that can also contain multiple replaceable tags to create templates. As on this picture [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fkDp.png)

In that picture, the information witch player (tag) made the goal would be stored.
Later I would reuse that template and replacing the tag by a value.
Like: Goal of Iniesta, Goal of Rivaldo, ...

I couldn't find a lib that would do the job. The few attempts that I made to try to resolve it lead to extremely complex inputs with redefining selects (onClick, onKeydown, onSelect, maintaining current select) as the user can't edit the tag by hand (they are trigger by clicking buttons).

Does somebody already had to handle this kind of input?

---

Edit: As my question seems to be not clear, I will add a few details.
In fact, the input should work as it is a free text input but should also allow adding tags/chips that are provided by external triggers (onClick buttons)

Example: I will make [activity] on [day]

First I **type "I will make "** then I click the **button "activity"** that will add a **"activity" tag/chip** to the input. I continue with **typing " on "** and finaly click the **button "day"** to add the **tag "day"**.

Then I will store this as template and reuse it in several scenarios by replacing the tags. Like:

- I will make sandwiches on Monday
- I will make sport on Friday

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://material-ui.com/components/chips/)

Comment: Hi @MatthewBenjamin 
Thank you for the link. These chip components don't seem to be usable with a free text input. I also looked in npm for a lib but the are just chip only inputs.
Do you know an implementation where it is combined with a free text input?

Comment: Could use something like `react-select`'s `CreatableSelect` with no `options`. Or this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-create-email-chips-in-pure-react-ad1cc3ecea16/ just remove the text validation for the email. 

Hope this helps! I might not be fully understanding the problem, though!

Comment: @MatthewBenjamin That's not the searched behavior, I will edit the question to make it more specific

Comment: Hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If somebody else have the same issue. I finally found the right lib [Tagify](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify). It has a mixed mode (text + tag)